# how to add to the lat of setCenter googlemaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an event listener to pan to a geolocated marker's coordinates on click. I would like the marker to be slightly south of center after I click it. Is it possible to add to the lat of these coordinates on my pan to function? Here is my code:

> ```
> for (let i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++){
>   geocoder.geocode( { address: someArray[i].full_address}, function(results, status) {
>       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
>           map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
>           let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>             map: map,
>             position: results[0].geometry.location
>           });
>           google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
>               if (!infowindow) {
>                   infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
>               }
>               infowindow.setContent(someArray[i].full_address);
>               infowindow.open(map, marker);
>               map.panTo(results[0].geometry.location);
>               map.setZoom(14);
>           });
> ```

For example if the coordinates of a marker are (35.11111, -102.11111) I would like, when I click on it, to pan to (35.11511, -102.11111). Pretty much though since they are ever changing if I click on a markers with the coordinates(x, y) i would pan to (x+.004, y)

Javascript only please.

Comment: What trouble are you having adding 0.004 to the latitude of the returned point? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you have tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want 0.004 degrees added to the latitude of the marker, add 0.004 to the latitude of the marker, then use that for the pan target.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      if (!infowindow) {
          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      }
      infowindow.setContent("full_address");
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      // add 0.004 to the marker latitude
      var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.getPosition().lat()+0.004, this.getPosition().lng());
      map.panTo(newLatLng);
      map.setZoom(14);
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/trzww8xg/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var latLng = map.getCenter();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latLng
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    if (!infowindow) {
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    }
    infowindow.setContent("full_address");
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.getPosition().lat() + 0.004, this.getPosition().lng());
    map.panTo(newLatLng);
    map.setZoom(14);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your `click` function and set the `LatLng`

```
var markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(52.5243, 13.4105);
marker.setPosition(markerPos);
```

Comment: The markers are set in the correct spot. When I click on them I want to pan  slightly north of the marker instead of the marker coordinates. For example if the coordinates of a marker are (35.11111, -102.11111) I would like when i click on it to pan to (35.11511, -102.11111). Pretty much though since they are ever changing if I click on  a markers with the coordinates(x, y) i would pan to (x+.004, y)